# c++ array iteration with addresses - heap corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, iteration, heap-corruption

I am new to c++ and trying out some stuff.
So recently I tried to create an int array on the heap and iterate it with addressation instead the standard way with [x].

Everytime I execute my code I get a heap corruption error.
I tried several things (also searched here on stackoverflow) but could not find any answers.

```
int* p = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    /*p[i] = i;
    cout << p[i] << endl;*/ //This is the standard way and works 

    *p = i;
    cout << *p << endl;

    p = (p + sizeof(*p)); //iterate the pointer through the heap addresses
}

delete[] p;
```

The application runs and shows me the filled array values {0,1,2,3,4} but then crashes.

I get following error message:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after CRT Block (#225) at 0x00C31B68.
CRT detected that application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is clearer to write the for loop as this `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` because it is simpler to compare the iteration limit 5 with the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = (p + sizeof(*p));
```

results in a jump of `4` with every iteration, as `sizeof(int)` is equal to `4`. Hence, you are going *out of bounds*.

The standard way, that is :

```
p[i] = i;
cout << p[i] << endl;
```

is correct, as `i` increases by `1` in every iteration.

Answer (score 5):

When you do this

```
p = (p + sizeof(*p));
```

you are taking `sizeof(int)` int-sized steps across the array, going beyond its bounds.

You need to take single steps:

```
p = (p + 1);
```

or

```
++p;
```

But note that after doing that, `p` no longer points to any place you can call `delete[]` on. You need to keep a pointer to the original address:

```
int* arr = new int[5];
int* p = arr;

....

delete[] arr;
```

But you have no reason to allocate the array with `new` in the first place.

```
int arr[5];
int * p = arr;
....
```

Comment: I thought I could get the address of the first array slot with the pointer p,
p = 0xSomething01
and then add an integer.
Then with adding the size of integer to the address i could get the next address.
So this does not work at all?

Comment: @Jazjef I thought it was clear from my answer. Pointer arithmetic takes care of the size of the objects being iterated over. `++p` means "increment the address of `p` by one `int`-sized step, i.e. make `p` point to the next `int`.

Comment: @Jazjef From your own code:  `cout << p[i] << endl;*/ //This is the standard way and works `  And `p[i]` is no different than `*(p + i)`.   See the similarities?  So how would you go to the next element in `p`.  Wouldn't you just increment `i` by 1?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Looks like I mixed some of the ideas of pointers and addresses :)

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
p = (p + sizeof(*p));
```

is wrong.

First of all you are changing the initial value of pointer p that points to the allocated memory.So this statement

```
delete[] p;
```

will be wrong for this pointer because initial value of p was changed.

Secondly expression `p + sizeof(*p)` means that you want to move the pointer right to sizeof( *p ) elements. If for example `sizeof( *p )` is equal to 4 then after statement

```
p = (p + sizeof(*p));
```

p will point to fifth element of the array (that is with index 4).

Valid code can look the following way

```
int* p = new int[5];

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    *( p + i ) = i;
    cout << *( p + i ) << endl;
}

delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 1):

In pointer arithmetics an expression `p + i`, where `p` is a pointer to an array's element and `i` is integer, is **equivalent** to `&(p[i])`, that is a pointer to the array's element `i` positions after the one pointed at by `p`.

That's why stepping to the next element is performed by `p = p+1` (or equvalently `p += 1` or simply `++p`).

Note however the incrementation does no checking for the array bounds – you're able to safely access the next item(s) *provided they belong to the same array*. If you step beyond the last item of an array you may get memory access error or just read some garbage.

See for example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm
https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html